# Validate textfield length

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I'm trying to validate text length in textField. Here is what I try

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *textLenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textField text]];
    if ([textLenght length] > 5)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" 
                                                message:@"Too long" 
                                                delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This code works well. The alert box is displayed when I type more than 5 characters. The problem is that when I try to delete the last character of textfield the alert box is displayed again.

How to fix that  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create the actual string first

```
NSString *str = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
```

You check the length afterwards

```
int length = str.length;
```

And continue with the if (length) checking.

This way first creates the required string (also taking into consideration the backspaces).

Comment: @Ariel as I've said in my answer, because the character user inputs may be a backspace and it will reduce the length of the string and the check logic will be correct.

Answer (score 2):

To check is the delete button has been pressed, you need to check that "string" isEqual to @"":

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

 if ([string isEqualToString:@""])...

}
```

Comment: You've forgot about copy/paste. I definitely can copy empty string and then paste it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to prevent the 5th symbol to be added from the start, and then you'll be fine with deletion...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"Enter");
    NSInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
    NSInteger newLength = oldLength + [string length] - range.length;
    if(newLength >= 5){
       return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```